# How do you make an HTML page get updates from my Java application?

Tags: java, html

Pretend I have an HTML page that's very basic, just some text that says "Counter: 1" and I want my Java application with just a simple button to send updates to the page through a server somehow to increase the counter. What tools would I need to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_a_WebSocket_server_in_Java

You should implement a webSocket and via that you can communicate java application with web site (html also)